# My computer boots to a black screen unless I run memtest

Tags: boot

Whenever I switch my old Dell E520 on first thing in the morning it fails to boot into Ubuntu 16.04. It gets through bios to grub & beyond but will stop while trying to load the os. It finishes at a black screen. This seems a common problem & I've tried all the suggested solutions appropriate to my setup from the [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) thread, but none have worked for me.

What seems different from any other solution or discussion offered is that I have found a strange workaround: if I get to grub & run memtest for a minute then press esc to reboot, all is well! This works every time.

My questions are: Can anyone suggest why this works? Is there a solution that does not need my intervention at grub?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you try and what happened? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

Add **nomodeset** to your grub commandline.

Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file.

Look for this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Append `nomodeset` to the line so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Now update your grub with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.

Comment: I have already tried that, & many other grub file alterations, but none have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a thermal problem, but it's reversed from the usual heat issues.  One of the connections in your system RAM slots is only making contact when the system has warmed up a bit -- as it'll do after one or more boot failures, or after running memtest for a short time.  Try removing and reseating your RAM modules, and you'll probably find the wiping action of the contacts brings back reliable connection and resolves the problem.

Comment: This certainly fits the fault profile. I'll try it over the weekend & report back. Thanks.